# How to click <a> anchor tag link only knowing its span with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On a web page there is this anchor that I want to click using Selenium:

```
<a onclick='ejecutaOpcion(this, '/srDocumentoAdmRecepcion.do?accion=goInicioGet&estadoDoc=01&coDep=10016','POST');' class='menu_lista' href='#'>
   <span>Recepción de Documentos</span>
</a>
```

There is no Id or Name for that anchor and class "menu_lista" is used for other anchors in same web page.

I've tried:

```
var recepcionLink = myWebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='menu_lista']/span[text()='Recepción de Documentos']"));
recepcionLink.Click();
```

However, I got exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.53)'

It looks like I'm getting the span element but not the anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using linktext.

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Recepción de Documentos']/../a).Click();
```

Comment: Doesn't catch element. `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Recepción de Documentos"}
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.53)'`

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try using that

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative locators (new in Selenium 4)

```
WebDriver.FindElement(RelativeBy
  .WithLocator(By.CssSelector("a.menu_lista span"))
  .Near(By.TagName("a")));
```

Docs
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/#available-relative-locators